# Echo sql data in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to retrieve data from my sql table. I insert in the table via bootstrap forms and I'd like to also be able to display it.

This is my query **SELECT meta_value FROM `wp__frm_item_metas` WHERE `item_id` = 2** and this is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBUmr.png)

This is my code

```
global $wpdb;
$centr = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT meta_value FROM `wp__frm_item_metas` WHERE `item_id` = 2');
echo $centr;
?>
```

However I am not getting the desired output. I only see *Array* printed out and I'd like to see the contents to be displayed like in the picture.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I provided an answer based on this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Yes, I was also reading that and but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into WordPress usage, it's going to be like this, because you have used the get_results method:

```
<?php

$centr = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT meta_value FROM `wp__frm_item_metas` WHERE `item_id` = 2');

if ( !empty( $centr ) ) {
    foreach ( $centr as $r ) {
        echo $r->meta_value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the first one and I didn't get any output. The second one however gave me an error "( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in index.php on line 63"

Comment: I updated my answer. You're dealing with an array of objects when you use the get_results method.

Comment: That worked, thanks. How can I add some breaks or spaces cause the current output is unreadable.

Comment: You could use `echo $r->meta_value . '<br />';` or `echo $r->meta_value . ' ';`